# Insert array PHALCON

Tags: php, vue.js, phalcon

I am trying to insert several data from an array but at the time of inserting it only inserts the last one I type.

This is my front-end code where I send the data

```
let payload = new FormData();
        for(var i = 0; i< this.addresses.length; i++) {
            payload.append('address', this.addresses[i].Adress)
            payload.append('city', this.addresses[i].City)
            payload.append('country', this.addresses[i].State)
        }
payload.append("customer_number", this.customer_number);
        payload.append("documents_email", this.documents_email);
        payload.append("address_address", this.address_address);
        payload.append("tenant_id", this.id);
        payload.append("address_countries", this.selectedStateAddress);
        payload.append("address_cities", this.selectedCityAddress);
        payload.append("name", this.name);
        payload.append("abbr", this.abbr);
        payload.append("email", this.email);
        payload.append("phone", this.phone);
        payload.append("contact", this.contact);
        payload.append("chamber_commerce", this.chamber_commerce);
        payload.append("vat", this.vat);
    

this.$http.post("/saveTenant", payload)
            .then(res => {
                this.datatenants = res.data.data;
                console.log("The client save");
            });
```

This is my Backend code where I am receiving the data

```
$address = $request ->getPost('address', 'string');
        $country_id = $request ->getPost('country', 'int');
        $city_id = $request ->getPost('city', 'int');
        $addresses = new TenantAddresses();
        $addresses->address           = $address;
        $addresses->country_id                = $country_id;
        $addresses->city_id                 = $city_id;

        if ($addresses->save() === false) {
          $this->db->rollback();
          return;
      }
```

This is what arrives in the data at the time of saving

That is the last data that I add, it is the only one that is saving
[image]

I do not know which is the correct way so that when I add more data to save it correctly, I hope that my doubt has been clear and you can collaborate with me.

I get constructive criticism as I am a bit new to programming. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like that `payload` does not contains an array of addresses. I would check the function `append` of the class `FormData`. I think the `append` function writes only one element at the time. Instead what you need is to send an array.

Comment: I have not been able to solve my concern, can you help me a little more?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an array of addresses, instead `FormData` sends only one address. Try to use an array like this:

```js
let payload = [];

for(var i = 0; i< this.addresses.length; i++) {
    payload.push({
        address: this.addresses[i].Adress,
        city: this.addresses[i].City,
        country: this.addresses[i].State
    });
}

this.$http.post("/saveTenant", { addresses: payload })
    .then(res => {
        this.datatenants = res.data.data;
        console.log("The client save");
    });
```

In your backend:

```php
$addresses = $request->getPost('addresses', 'array');

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, but I need to send it yes or yes in FormData so that the data reaches the backend. Any other solution?

Comment: you need to adjust your backend to look for ```addresses``` instead of ```address``` ---> ```$request ->getPost('address', 'string');``` then loop though the array saving each address

Comment: Could you give me an example to put me in context, I would appreciate it very much !!

Comment: do as @Dan suggested but you should name the addresses ```this.$http.post("/saveTenant", { addresses: payload })``` and in your backend you can get the addresses ```$request->getPost('addresses', 'string');``` that should return an array of ```{ address, city, country }```

Comment: I already edited the question a bit since I send I am sending more data, not just the addresses. The way they tell me does not work when I want to send more data, I have to use the FormData

Comment: to fully understand does ```$request ->getPost('address', 'string');``` return an array when using FormData ? if it does then you need loop through the array if not can you provide the request params coming to the backend

Comment: If in your frontend you post the addresses like this `this.$http.post("/saveTenant", { addresses: payload })` in your backend you should be able to get an array doing like this: `$addresses = $request->getPost('addresses', 'array');` (I also updated the example above)